# Proving technology of Coq's kernel

Tags: coq

Isabelle bases its kernel proof power in resolution coupled with higher-order unification.

How are theorems proven by Coq's kernel?

The question arises from reading Paulson's "The foundation of a generic theorem prover":

> Propositions-as-types could consume excessive space; and what would take the place of Huet's unification procedure for higher-order logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two kinds of technology in most provers: the "proving" part (responsible for building a proof, since it is often too tedious for the user) and the "checking" part (responsible for verifying that a proof is well-formed and matches a given theorem statement). In both Isabelle and Coq, the kernel is only responsible for the "checking" part.

In the case of Coq, the propositions-as-types paradigm is indeed used for checking proofs. In other words, a proof is a lambda-term of the Calculus of Inductive Constructions (CIC) whose type is compared to the theorem statement seen as a type.

Answer (score 2):

> How are theorems proven by Coq's kernel?

As explained above, theorems are *not* proven by Coq's kernel, only *checked*.

That check is done as usual with type checking:  If the term is an application, check (recursively) that the arguments has the right type, and that the function return type matches the type.  For example, to prove that `a + f(b)` has type `nat`, you must check that `plus` has type `nat -> nat -> nat`, that `f` has type `A -> nat`, that `a` has type `nat` and `b` has type `A`.

The proof has to be constructed by the user.  The *proof* itself is a *lambda term*.  The theorem *proposition* is the *type* of the lambda term.

Because it may be difficult to create the right lambda term directly, Coq does not force  the user to write the whole term in one go. One can instead leave "holes" in the term to be filled in later, either by hand or with `tactics`.  Tactics are small programs that try to fill in a piece of the proof (which may or may not be the right piece...).

Once the entire lambda term has been constructed, the proof is *checked* by Coq by checking that the lambda term really has the type of the proposition that one wishes to prove.